# Foreground image / Texture for Text

Tags: javascript, css, image, text, background

Is there any JS / CSS solution for a background image layer on text itself?

**Example**

[image]

Comment: You mean a texture or foreground image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/

Comment: I was trying to find this Lea Verou article and then got distracted. It pretty much answers the OP's question.